# ¿Es posible abrir un link en particular predeterminadamente con una WebView App?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview-android

Tengo una WebView App en Android, la cual está diseñada solo para navegar en cierto sitio. Lo que quisiera es que cuando se comparta el link de este sitio y se quiera abrir, hacerlo automáticamente con mi WebView App.

Algo así como cuando Facebook o Instagram abren los links pertenecientes a sus webs con su app nativa en android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuelto, usando Intent Filter.
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking?hl=es

Yo quería que todos los links https://www.alterego.nat.cu/ se abrieran diréctamente con una app webview que creé para interectuar con el sitio. Lo resolví declarando en el archivo AndroidManifest.xml justo como hijo de la Activity en la que se encuentra declarado la webview el siguiente Intent Filter.

```xml
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
               <data android:scheme="https"
                   android:host="www.alterego.nat.cu"/>
           </intent-filter>
```

Para más información consultar el link de arriba el cual pertenece a la documentación oficial de android.

Comment: Expande y explica tu solución para que otros menos experimentados aprendan y la puedan aplicar.